# what's the easiest way to detect the given object is value or reference type in .net?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

What's the way to check if an `object` is a `value` type or `reference` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
o.GetType().IsValueType
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`IsValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) like this:

```
if (yourObject.GetType().IsValueType) {
    // it's a value type
} else {
    // it's a reference type
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They already answered, but don't forget that, if an object is an instance of a class, then it is a reference type, and if an object is an "instance" of a struct, then it is a value type. But there is an exception. String is a reference type but behaves like value type, because of a immutability.

Comment: In what way does `string` behave like a value type?

Comment: if you pass a string as argument to a method, and modify it, after the method finish, the string value still the original value, so it doesnt finish with any change that the method did.